# serviceWorker.ready never resolves unless within setTimeout

Tags: service-worker, domready, background-sync

In a page's domready event I'm setting an event listener for a button that sets a Background Sync event in a page on my website (when offline), but even if the service worker has been loaded already on previous page visits, this line of code never resolves the promise, its status stays "Pending" indefinitely.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (sw) {
    $('#elt').on('click', function () {
         sw.sync.register('contact-form-submission');
```

Since I know the sync event won't need to be set until after a form is completed, I tried wrapping this code in a setTimeout() of 3 seconds, which worked! My question is why this might be, I haven't been able to find anyone else indicating the .ready event wouldn't be available when the page is first loaded. Insight appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I did not, setTimeout remains

Comment: OK. In my application with Firebase Cloud Messaging, I can't get ready to ever fire, so I use navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations() to get a service worker registration...